# simpleModal to update form

Tags: jquery-plugins, simplemodal

To all:

I am trying to update a form input radio button(s) using simplemodal to display the div containing the radio buttons.

It displays correctly however when the modal is closed the change is lost.

is their a simple call back that can update my form?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Bob,

What exactly are you trying to do? By default, SimpleModal does not maintain form state. You can try adding the persist:true option to the modal, but there are still some issues with certain browsers.

-Eric

Comment: Eric,

Thanks for your response and your plugin.

after reading more of your doc's I saw the persist option - but as you know that does not work in IE 6 & & for radio buttons. I worked arround this by using your onSow

$('#triggerID').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();  
 $('#divModalId').modal({onShow: function (dialog) {
  $('input:radio', dialog.data).click(function () {
   var anyName = jQuery('#divModalId input:radio:checked').val();
   $('#hiddenInputId').val(anyName);
  });
 }});
 $("#divModalId").modal({persist:true});
 });
});
I will let you know how it turns out.

Bob